# Issue executing a command with cmd.exe

Tags: c#, cmd

I've got an issue executing this code:

```
Process arp = new Process();
arp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
arp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
arp.StartInfo.FileName = "C://Windows//System32//cmd.exe";
arp.StartInfo.Arguments = "arp -a";
arp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
arp.Start();
arp.WaitForExit();
string output = arp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

The program should put the output of arp-a into the String output but it gives me back this instead:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]\r\nCopyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\Users\user01\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\freehotspotexploiter\freehotspotexploiter\bin\Debug>

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: `cmd.exe` doesn't take parameters like that.  If you want to execute `arp`, just execute it directly.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but your slashes in the file path are the wrong direction. And to make it easier, you can just do `cmd.exe`. It's already in the PATH environment variable, so it will work without a fully path.

Comment: Does a project named FreeHotspotExploiter deserve an answer?

Comment: it was a name like other, don't be kiddy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to send a command to cmd.exe as an argument, use the "/c" flag.

```
arp.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c arp -a";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command name should be `arp` not `cmd.exe`

Replace This:

```
arp.StartInfo.FileName = "C://Windows//System32//cmd.exe";
arp.StartInfo.Arguments = "arp -a";
```

With This:

```
arp.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
arp.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a";
```

Comment: Assuming there is no need for `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi There is `arp` command: http://www.computerhope.com/arphlp.htm