# Arguments not run while executing CMD through a winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cmd, ping

I created a windows form application that runs a ping command when a button is pressed. I previously asked the question "Is there any way that I could copy the output from the CMD window to the clipboard?" without realizing that when the process is executed no command is run. It just opens CMD.

This is what I am using to run the CMD process:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
//startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = pingData;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Here is the code behind "pingData", what I am using for my argument:

```
pingData = "ping s0" + textBox1.Text + "r100";
```

textBox1 only has up to 4 numbers at a given time.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you just run this in CMD? (Not by code, just type command in CMD and see the result)

Comment: It pings one of the routers connected to that hostname.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue executing a command with cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306258/issue-executing-a-command-with-cmd-exe)

Comment: you should `cmd /c ping s0...` (add /c to the arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `/C` to your arguments list and then the command name and its arguments.
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

**Do note:** this question has been asked & answered already: [Issue executing a command with cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306258/issue-executing-a-command-with-cmd-exe)